# On Ubuntu 20.04 the clipboard is cleared when I log out. Is this the same behaviour as on other systems?

Tags: clipboard, copy, logout, paste, copy-and-paste

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Ubuntu clears the clipboard content after logging out.
So let's say that I copied a piece of text before logging out and I logged in again, the text can't be pasted. I don't want that to happen.

Is this an issue specific to my device or Ubuntu 20.04, or Ubuntu generally clears clipboard content in previous Ubuntu versions as well?

Comment: Would never expect another behaviour from any OS. For me, that behavior is obvious and it works exactly as it should. If you are logging out, that means you are destroying all temporary data connected with your session, inluding clipboard. Clipboard is by definition temporary; it was never meant to be persistent.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux the clipboard isn't a place to store data but a way of communication between programs:

- If a program copies data to the clipboard it actually doesn't copy anything but just registers itself as the clipboard owner and waits for clipboard-related messages from other programs.
- If a program wants to paste data from the clipboard it sends a message to the clipboard owner and requests data in some particular format (like e.g. text). The clipboard owner then answers with data in that format or an error if can't provide data in that format.

After logging out there is no clipboard owner so you can't paste from the clipboard.

There are clipboard managers, e.g. diodon or parcellite, that provide additional features for the clipboard. Maybe you can find one that can preserve the clipboard content between sessions.

Comment: I want to inform you that I've modified the question a bit. But I guess the answer is still apt.

Comment: Does clipboard behave the same in Windows/mac OS?

Comment: @technastic_tc the clipboard is already known to be a security risk iirc (because arbitrary programs may be able to read from it). Keeping the content across user sessions would horribly exacerbate that, I think.

Comment: @Zanna What if there's only one user?

Comment: What if we lock the screen instead of log out?